# Groovy: variable assignment

Tags: java, groovy

I'm about to take a course in computer science and have some decent knowledge in T-SQL and that's it.

The pre reading for this course is not well written. Having trouble how they are getting certain result sets. Here is `Groovy` statement

```
String str
print "Please key in a word: "
str = System.console().readline() 
print "The word was: "
println str
```

Result

```
Please key in a word: Tom
The word was : Tom
```

Where on earth did they assign or set `str = "Tom"`. I understand variables but have never come across `system.console().readLine()` so maybe i am missing something? 
Clearly the pre reading is meant to suggest that I type in value Tom but actually hasn't bothered to show me where.

Regards

Tom

Comment: that was user input. `console.readLine()` listens to keyboard inputs (until the enter). that "Tom" was shown as an example input in console

Answer (score 2):

`readline()` is a method. It does `return` something. In this case a string.

`str = System.console().readline()` is an assignment because you use `=`, the assignment operator.

Comment: Hi Zero, so in layman 's terms for me where did they put Tom in the above statement?

Comment: You typed it into the console.

Comment: `str = System.console().readline()` says, assign the value returned by the method `System.console().readline()` to the variable `str` and `System.console().readline()` return what is entered on the terminal.